# NSLayoutConstraints not setting (swift 3)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nslayoutconstraint

I'm using text data from core data to size a message container frame however it appears that the frame isn't being set fast enough if that makes sense. I tried putting the code in override layoutSubviews and setupViews to no avail.

Below is the code for setting the messageContainer frame

```
    if let messageText = cell?.text {
        let size = CGSize(width: 100, height: 40)
        let options = NSStringDrawingOptions.usesFontLeading.union(.usesLineFragmentOrigin)
        let estimatedFrame = NSString(string: messageText).boundingRect(with: size, options: options, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 12)], context: nil)



        messageContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        messageContainer.frame.size.width = estimatedFrame.width
        messageContainer.frame.size.height = estimatedFrame.height



        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageLabel, attribute: .left , relatedBy: .equal, toItem: messageContainer, attribute: .left, multiplier: 1, constant: 5))

        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageLabel, attribute: .width , relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: messageContainer, attribute: .width, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))

        addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageLabel, attribute: .height , relatedBy: .lessThanOrEqual, toItem: messageContainer, attribute: .height, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))



    }
```

Right now the text just runs off the screen and does not wrap.

Any suggestions?

Edit: I have included a screenshot of what the container should look like behind the messageLabel. The difference between this build and the current one is that the current one is using auto layout which I believe is what's causing the issue...
[image]

Comment: Is this inside a table view cell ? Can you draw / show in a picture the structure of the views and what you are hoping to achieve ?

Comment: updated question. Also this is a UICollectionView cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Problem:

Based on the constraint you have set the auto layout system imposes:

**messageLabel.width <= messageContainer.width**

But this might not what you intend.

## Solution:

What your real intention is to impose restriction on the right.

- Remove the width constraint.
- Don't set the frame of `messageContainer`, use constraints.
- Set all this in the cell's initialiser.

**messageLabel.right <= messageContainer.right**

Code:

```
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: messageLabel, attribute: .right , relatedBy: . lessThanOrEqual, toItem: messageContainer, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: -5))
```

## Note:

Please test it and see if it matches your requirements.

## Preferred Solution:

It would be good if you could use the following:

- `UIStackView` - https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uistackview
- Layout anchors instead of layout constraints. - https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html